# How can I access Specifical Data in an object through Generic arrayList?

Tags: java, object, generics, arraylist

Here I have a question about how to access specifical Data inside object named **Car** through Generic List object

-Here is my class *Car.java*

```
public class Car {
    public String name;
    public double price;
    public String production;
    public Car(String name,double price,String pro){
     this.name=name;
     this.price=price;
     this.production=pro;
     
    }
    public String getName(){return this.name;}
    public double getPrice(){return this.price;}
    public String getProduction(){return this.production;}
}
```

*And I want to access **name** of Car object through generic by the **DisplayCarName()** method but something wrong happened,the compilation failed at "**u.get(i).getName();**"

-Here is my *GenericCar.java*

```
public class GenericCar <T> {
    List<T>u ;
    GenericCar(){
     u = new ArrayList<T>();
    }
   public void Add(T x){
        u.add(x);
    }
   //i want to display only Car class,specifically name of car,but it seems not work!
   public void DisplayCarName(){
    for(int i=0;i<u.size();i++){
        System.out.println(u.get(i).getName());
    }
   }
}
```

*In my Main class, I can't use this method **car2.DisplayCarName();**  in generic class

```
public class Main() {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        GenericCar<Car>car2= new GenericCar<Car>();
        car2.Add(new Car("Toyota",20.3,"Toyota"));
        //use this ok!
        System.out.println(car2.u.get(0).getName());
        //but this is not!
        car2.DisplayCarName(); 
    } 
}
```

*All about my question is "How to access specifical Data inside object named **Car** through Generic List object,Sorry about long question!"

Comment: The name of your class `GenericCar` makes no sense. A "generic car" has-a list? Of what? How is this not just a `List<Car>`?

Comment: I want to make more sense of Generic so I do the test for this purpose :(((

Comment: You seem to have generics backward. Generic means "a data structure (like a list or a set) that can accept various different (generic) types of contents"; you seem to be looking for either the [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) or [Delegate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) patterns.

Answer (score 2):

T can be any class in `GenericCar<T>`, not just Car, so the compiler doesn't know that "getName" refers to the method in Car.

Here's one way to fix it. You can use a *bound* for the type variable to tell the compiler that T actually has to be some kind of Car:

```
class GenericCar<T extends Car>
```

Comment: Thank for this answer,Which I really need!

Comment: „*...Thank for this answer,Which I really need!...*“ —  @DEV-WEB, I'm curious. What's your reason for not accepting Joni's answer? Thanks in advance.